# why Admissible heuristics work?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, a-star, heuristics

I came across the term admissible heuristics in context of A* Search algorithm. Can someone explain (or give an intuition) why the heuristic function h is admissible only if it doesn't over-estimate the actual distance?

Comment: Did you read the Wikipedia page?

Comment: Do you understand the reason why in A* the heuristic must not overestimate the remaining distance to the goal?

Comment: @RonTeller Let's say *should*.

Comment: @RonTeller  no thats exactly what im asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about the stopping condition of A*, the algorithm stops if it reaches the goal node with a certain `F` value, where `F` equals `G`- the path constructed so far from the starting point plus the heuristic value `H` which represents an estimation of the remaining path to the goal.

At the goal node, `F` equals `G` as the estimation of the remaining path to the goal is 0.

The stopping condition is valid only if `H` is admissible, since then we can determine that if the `F` value we calculated at the goal node is smaller than any other `F` value we calculated in any other node, we can surely determine it is the shortest path, as no other path may reach the goal with a smaller `F` value.

If it wouldn't be admissible, then there may be some other node for whom we calculated `F` with an overestimation of the remaining path to the goal, and we can't stop the algorithm as a shorter path may exist.

Answer (score 1):

For those who do not seek the resources provided free of cost and free of effort.

> In computer science, specifically in algorithms related to
>   pathfinding, a heuristic function is said to be admissible if it never
>   overestimates the cost of reaching the goal, i.e. the cost it
>   estimates to reach the goal is not higher than the lowest possible
>   cost from the current point in the path. An admissible heuristic is
>   also known as an optimistic heuristic.

This is a link to Wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic

## Concerning the second question

A heuristic is admissible when it doesn't overestimate the true cost, simply because it is defined this way.

Comment: ok, instead of being cocky you should read my question again.....i am asking for an intuition why this is true in context of A* search. Wikipedia doesn't give any arguments in support of it.....it just states the facts.

Comment: @ishan3243 To be fair my last sentence gives the sole correct answer to your question. It's simply defined this way.

Comment: I don't believe so.....there has to be a reason behind why it is defined like that.. If you see the other answer I think its somewhat explained

Comment: Of course, there is a reason (for which you didn't ask): A* with admissible heuristic (and some further assumptions) yields optimal results.

Comment: i don't have time for this.....thank u for your time anyways :)   I appreciate it...